# ShellToast Navigation in notification

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation, notifications, scheduled-tasks

I am using ShellToast in ScheduledAgent.cs on my App, when I want to click on notification display by ShellToast, I want to navigate to different my second page, but when I try it nothing happen

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
   var toast = new ShellToast
   {
        Title = "KWTtest",
        Content = toastMessage
    };
    toast.NavigationUri = new Uri("/View/SettingsPage.xaml", 
    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    toast.Show();
    NotifyComplete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct code. It works in my application.
You get a toast notification?
If you click on the notification, the application does not open completely?
Or application is opened after you click on the notification, but start on the main page?

Comment: exactly, application is opened on MainPage, also I tried use new Uri("/View/MainPage.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification", UriKind.Absolute), and check query string on MainPage in OnNavigatedTo   string navigatedFrom;
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("NavigatedFrom", out navigatedFrom))
            { ... }
but queryString seems empty

Comment: For the sample code shown in your issue of additional action is needed.

You will receive a toast notification, click on the notification automatically runs your application on a page, specified by the Property toast.NavigationUri.

Try to set a breakpoint in the debugger in app.xaml.cs

For example, `async private void InitializeLicensing ()` and the forward step by step.

Perhaps somewhere in your application changes the navigation frame.

This can be in one of the methods in app.xaml.cs.

Or MainPage.xaml.cs in the `OnNavigatedTo`, etc.

Comment: You helped me a lot with information that in your application it is work, I don't know why but it is worked now, I just add #define DEBUG_AGENT of course I hope when I will delete it it will work again